Why an error occurred after connection was established successfully in an ASP.NET Core 9 Web API?
I have an ASP.NET Core 9 Web API project with SQL Server 2019, and the connection string is defined in the appsettings.json as shown below:
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source = .; initial Catalog = serverAPI9; Trusted_Connection = true" }
}

Also, the connection is configured in the Program.cs like this:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

While performing a POST action, the _context.SaveChangesAsync(); method throws the following error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

How to solve this problem?

Try to add Trust Server Certificate=True to connectionString

Setup the correct certificates to secure your solution. A tiny bit of internet searching will show that this is a common problem.

As per my suggestion.
You do not specified the login part in the connection string

Like if you have to connect sql server with the Windows Based Authentication then use Integrated Security=True;
Server=server;Database=database-name;Connect Timeout=120;Encrypt=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True;

Used SQL Server Authentication then Use User ID=usename; Password=password;
Server=server;Database=database-name;User ID=username;Password=password;Connect Timeout=120;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

Use TrustServerCertificate=true when you connect server using Window Based Authentication for the SQL Server Authentication we do not required


Please find out related document from the official Microsoft site :Connection string syntax

This is a breaking change from .NET 7 times - Encrypt defaults to true for SQL Server connections:

SqlClient connection strings use Encrypt=True by default. This means that:

The server must be configured with a valid certificate
The client must trust this certificate


From the Mitigations section of the docs:

There are three ways to proceed:

Install a valid certificate on the server. Note that this is an involved process and requires obtaining a certificate and ensuring it is signed by an authority trusted by the client.
If the server has a certificate, but it is not trusted by the client, then TrustServerCertificate=True to allow bypassing the normal trust mechanism.
Explicitly add Encrypt=False to the connection string.



I added "Encrypt=False" in connection string:  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source = .; initial Catalog = serverAPI9; Trusted_Connection = true; Encrypt=False", but the _context.SaveChangesAsync(); method throws the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "serverAPI9" requested by the login. The login failed.

@R.Nourmandi that usually means that you have not provided valid credentials.

Use like given connection string :
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "dbcs": "Server=Your Server Connection;Database=App5;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
 },

